# issue populating v$session properties in oracle datasource

Tags: java, spring, jpa, oracle11g, tomcat6

I have a issue populating v$session properties in oracle datasource ie after starting tomcat server my application would be using connection , now if I query DB with below query I should get a row from DB, currently I am not getting any row for 1st approach ,but 2nd approach works

```
 select schemaname, osuser, machine, program
 from v$session
 where program = 'Test';
```

below are the configuration and tools I am using , any help regaring this is appriciated .

Thanks

```
1.Tomcate 6.0.35.3 
2.Oracle version :Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
3.Spring and JPA
```

Approach 1:-

server.xml :

```
                            <Resource 
                                            name="jdbc/oraclepool"
                                            auth="Container"
                                            factory="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl" 
                                            type="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource"
                                            description="main DB"
                                            connectionFactoryClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
                                            connectionPoolName="UCPPool"
                                            url="${db.url}"
                                            user="${db.username}"
                                            password="${db.password.encrypted}"
                                            initialPoolSize="3"
                                            minPoolSize="1" 
                                            maxPoolSize="5"
                                            maxIdleTime="${db.maxIdleTime}"
                                            inactiveConnectionTimeout="${db.inactiveConnectionTimeout}" 
                                            abandonedConnectionTimeout="${db.abandonedConnectionTimeout}"
                                            timeToLiveConnectionTimeout="${db.timeToLiveConnectionTimeout}"
                                            maxStatements="${db.maxOpenPreparedStatements}"
                                            timeoutCheckInterval="${db.timeoutCheckInterval}"
                                            connectionWaitTimeout="${db.connectionWaitTimeout}"
                                            sqlForValidateConnection="${db.validationQuery}" 
                                            connectionProperties="v$session.program=Test;"
                                            />
```

Approach 2 :-

Added below code snippet in java class , it worked .

When I queried the db with below query , I was getting the row .

```
  select schemaname, osuser, machine, program
  from v$session
  where program = 'Test';

    Connection conn=null;
 // set connection properties
    Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
    info.put("v$session.program", "Test");
    // connect to database
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    PoolDataSourceImpl ds = (PoolDataSourceImpl)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/oraclepool");
    ((PoolDataSourceImpl)ds).setConnectionProperties(info); 
    conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Can anybody tell what is the issue with first approach

Thanks again .

Comment: You should mention what the issue is that you're facing. It's not clear from your explanation.

Comment: edited the question , let me know if you need more info , Thanks

Comment: Excellent question.